# $variable in template_part wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to make an option in theme for related posts
I want to display two different related posts ,one by tags and other by categories but I want to give the possibility to choose it from theme panel

My code in relatedposts.php

```
$relatedposts = get_option('theme_relatedoptions');
if (get_option('theme_relatedoptions') <> '') { 
get_template_part( 'templates/related/'.$relatedposts.'', get_post_format() );
} else {
get_template_part( 'templates/related/tags', get_post_format() );   
}
```

Code in Admin Functions

```
$options[] = array( "name" => __('Related Videos','framework'),
"id" => $shortname."_relatedoptions",
    "type" => "radio",
    "options" => array("tags", "category"),
    "std" => "tags");
```

tags.php in related folder displays related posts by tags
and category.php displays the relatedposts by category but I dont know where so,
Im not sure here
get_template_part( 'templates/related/'.$relatedposts.'', get_post_format() );

Can anyone help me? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually pass a `$variable` directly to a template called with `get_template_part();` because the files are `required`: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part

To use a variable directly within `get_template_part();` you need to declare the variable as global or pass a custom `$arg` to `WP_Query`.

That being said I don't see why you would need to pass a variable to get_template_part(); directly here. Could you simply read the variable (the category or tag in this case) and then pass that to WP_Query as an argument somewhat similar to this:

`$query = new WP_Query( 'tag='$variable );`

Comment: is there another way to use instead of the get_template_part to make this? because as you see in admin I have "options" => array("tags", "category"), So when I choose category I want that relatedposts change to category.php something like '$variable'.php sorry Im a starter

Comment: No need to apologize for being a starter, we were all a starter once :) I do need to apologize though because I think I have misunderstood your question and given you an incorrect answer. Could you clarify what the problem is a bit for me? Your saying you want to display the posts of a specific tag or category (set by the user on an options page in the dashboard) on a page? Which page do you want it displayed on, because that affects where you need to put the code, and what do you have inside of the templates your referencing?

Comment: thanks for the responses testing , testing and testing finaly I figuret it out  using another way           `$relatedposts = get_option('theme_relatedoptions');
if ($relatedposts == "tags") {
get_template_part( 'inc/related/tags', get_post_format() ); 
} elseif ($related_by == "category") { 
get_template_part( 'templates//related/category', get_post_format() ); 
} else {
get_template_part( 'templates//related/tags', get_post_format() ); 
}`  thanks